# Automatically Disable Night Light when fullscreen?

Tags: games, fullscreen, night-light

Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome DE

When I go fullscreen in stuff like games or youtube, I'd like night light to automatically disable, is this possible?

I like to have it always on to reduce eyestrain for every other activity.

Answer (score 1):

***Workaround***

until experts write the correct way.. you may do the following trick..

install the packages xdotool and wmctrl with below command

```
sudo apt install xdotool wmctrl
```

then create a script with below content and bind the script with any keyboard shortcut you wish.

```
#!/bin/bash

wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,fullscreen

WINDOW=$(echo $(xwininfo -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) -stats | \
                egrep '(Width|Height):' | \
                awk '{print $NF}') | \
         sed -e 's/ /x/')
SCREEN=$(xdpyinfo | grep -m1 dimensions | awk '{print $2}')

if [ "$WINDOW" != "$SCREEN" ]; then
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled false
else
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled true
fi
```

I Have used the shortcut Alt+N to run the command `/bin/bash nl.sh`

[image]

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/30414/739431

Comment: Interesting. If I understand this correctly, would you have to run this everytime you've opened a full screen program? Or just once at every reboot?

Comment: no no, you have to manually use the shortcut to make any window full screen.. meaning.. with any active window press the keyboard shortcut to toggle on and off.. the script will verify the screen is full screen or not and activate night light accordingly.. I have tested this in Ubuntu 19.10 but cant capture bcoz screen recorder cant show the difference.

Comment: Gotcha... I have installed a gnome extension that adds a night light slider below the volume slider. I think I'll just adjust the slider to zero when I'm about to play a full screen game or something. Since your workaround still requires manual interaction. I appreciate your suggestion though and I may still try it out.